# Is it possible to force the currency for an MVC3 field with DataType as DataType.Currency

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, globalization, currency

I'm writing an MVC3 application that reads in a bunch of monetary data from a database. The issue I have is that these amounts are all in different currencies.

If I set the type of a field like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public Amount{ get; set;}
```

I get the decimal places and a currency symbol, which looks nice, but it defaults to the user's local currency. A US user sees `$423.29` whereas a GB user sees `£423.29`. I can override the currency by using a `<globalization culture="{something}">` in the Web.config, but this sets all currency fields globally.

What would be the easiest way of marking up a field so that it renders with the correct decimal places and currency symbol?

In an ideal world, I'd like to be able to do something like this (for USD):

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency, culture="en-us")]
public Amount{ get; set; }
```

and have that always render as `$439.38`, but that's not possible with the built-in annotations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way I would do this is to create a custom attribute that extends the `DataType` attribute and a custom html helper. It's not necessarily the *easiest* way of doing it but it would save time in the future.

**EDIT**
Incorporated `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName)` instead of a `switch`

**Custom Attribute**

```
public class CurrencyDisplayAttribute : DataTypeAttribute
{
    public string Culture { get; set; }

    public CurrencyDisplayAttribute(string culture)
        : base(DataType.Currency)
    {
        Culture = culture;
    }
}
```

**Html Helper**

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static IHtmlString CurrencyDisplayFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        double value = double.Parse(expression.Compile().Invoke(helper.ViewData.Model).ToString());
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);

        var prop = typeof (TModel).GetProperty(metadata.PropertyName);

        var attribute = prop.GetCustomAttribute(typeof (CurrencyDisplayAttribute)) as CurrencyDisplayAttribute;

        // this should be whatever html element you want to create
        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("span");
        tagBuilder.SetInnerText(value.ToString("c", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(attribute.Culture));

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
```

You can use the attribute in your model

```
[CurrencyDisplay("en-us")]
public double Amount { get; set; }
```

Then in your view you can use the helper by

```
@Html.CurrencyDisplayFor(x => x.Amount);
```

Provided your model is passed in correctly.

Obviously, you'd need to do error checking and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Make string the amount

```
public string Amount{ get; set;}
```

Create a method that converts to string with currency exact

```
private string LocalizedAmount(decimal theAmount, string cultureName)
{
      return theAmount.ToString("c",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName));
}
```

If you are stored in your database two fields or columns one for value and one for culture.

And in the Repository or the controller:

```
Amount = LocalizedAmount(Convert.ToDecimal(reader[0]),reader[1].ToString());
```

Comment: +1 This could be incorporated with my answer and would mean he wouldn't need to change the type of the property, which could cause problems elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, but as I understand you will get a List<Product> as product has Amount property, that each product has its own currencty. How can you accomplish manage dinamyc currency in your response? If you need use it to complete your response go ahead!

Comment: I don't see anywhere the OP states he is getting a `List<Product>` - or am I missing something? I'm just going from his "ideal world" statement, which is exactly what my answer provides. I didn't think about the `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture` solution though, that's really nice :)

Comment: I supposed it from this message of the author: Not in the slightest. I don't care what culture the user is in. I care about what currency the monetary data is in, and displaying it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You need to assing the culture:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName);
```

Inside this Controller overrided methods:

```
 protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
 protected override void ExecuteCore()
```

Read the whole technique in this NadeemAfana's blog [ASP.NET MVC 3 Internationalization](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx)

Comment: How would this help if the same controller needs to render fields in USD, GBP and (say) EUR?

Comment: if you should render according to the culture of each user, this will help. Is this your need?

Comment: Not in the slightest. I don't care what culture the user is in. I care about what currency the monetary data is in, and displaying it accordingly.

Comment: Is not a way with standarized DataType, but, if you change the Data to string, and parse with .ToString("c",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureName)); You will return a number in each currency and returning the symbol of the currency