# Changing the currency sign in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently new to asp.net MVC and I have this

```
[Range(1, 1000)]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Now, it displays the dollar sign as an output. Is there any way I could change it into Php (Philippine Peso)?

Comment: Set the culture in your app and it will be displayed in the format for that culture

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408530/is-it-possible-to-force-the-currency-for-an-mvc3-field-with-datatype-as-datatype check this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ISO-639/ISO-3166 country-language codes](https://www.fincher.org/Utilities/CountryLanguageList.shtml), the proper value for Filipino culture stored in `CultureInfo` is `fil-PH`, hence you need to configure the UI/site culture code in web.config file to show its currency in view (this configuration apply for entire application):

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.web>
        <globalization culture="fil-PH" uiCulture="fil-PH" />
    </system.web>
    ...
</configuration>
```

As an alternative, creating custom attribute to include culture & language code on currency input can be used as given [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12409501/) using same language code provided above.

Similar issue:

[Change the Currency Symbol thoroughout the Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629225/change-the-currency-symbol-thoroughout-the-application)